# Running a command as a background process/service

Tags: bash, shell, unix, service, background-process

I have a Shell command that I'd like to run in the background and I've read that this can be done by suffixing an `&` to the command which causes it to run as a background process but I need some more functionality and was wondering how to go about it:

1. I'd like the command to start and run in the background every time the system restarts.
2. I'd like to be able to able to start and stop it as and when needed just like one can do `service apache2 start`.

How can I go about this? Is there a tool that allows me to run a command as a service?

I'm a little lost with this.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, a Unix "service" is usually called a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) - knowing this may help you find information more easily.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at the [daemon](http://www.libslack.org/daemon/) command, which can turn arbitrary processes into daemons. This will allow your script to act as a daemon without requiring you to do a lot of extra work. The next step is to invoke it automatically at boot. To know the correct way to do that, you'll need to provide your OS (or, for Linux, your distribution).

Comment: Cheers Sorpigal. That helped.

Comment: Hi Sorpigal. I know I've already accepted this answer but could you tell how I could get the daemon to start on startup. I'm on Ubuntu 10.4. Thanks.

Comment: @MridangAgarwalla: I'm not very familiar with Ubuntu's new init system, but [try here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) and in the Writing Services section put your daemon invocation where it says `echo "Put bash code here"`

Answer (score 26):

UNIX systems can handle as many processes as you need simultaneously (just open new shell windows if you're in a GUI), so running a process in the background is only necessary if you need to carry on using the current shell window for other things once you've run an application or process that keeps running.

To run a command called *command* in background mode, you'd use:

```
command &
```

This is a special character that returns you to the command prompt once the process is started. There are other special characters that do other things, more info is available [here](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_tools/_Special_Characters.html).

Comment: The advantage of using Sorgigal's solution is that you can close the terminal/shell process, and the process will continue running. This is not the case using &, as the process remains attached to the particular shell process, and exits if the shell process does.

Comment: To keep `command` running after closing shell, use `nohup command &`

Answer (score 3):

Based on this article:
<del>http:// felixmilea.com/2014/12/running-bash-commands-background-properly/</del>

...another good way is with `screen` eg:

```
screen -d -m -s "my session name" <command to run>
```

from the [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Invoking-Screen.html):

> `-d -m`
>   Start screen in detached mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

i.e. you can close your terminal, the process will continue running (unlike with `&`)

with `screen` you can also reattach to the session later

Comment: The `felixmilea.com` domain no longer exists and the link redirects randomly to a phishing page.

Answer (score 2):

For advanced job control with bash, you should look into the commands `jobs` `bg` and `fg`.

However, it seems like you're not really interested in running the command in the background. What you want to do is launch the command at startup. The way to do this varies depending on the Unix system you use, but try to look into the `rc` family of files (`/etc/rc.local` for example on Ubuntu). They contain scripts that will be executed after the init script.

Comment: I know that this isn't the solution for OP, but if someone swings by this answer, it is helpful to know that you can "disown" jobs and they will keep running in the background even after the shell exits.

Answer (score 2):

Use nohup while directing the output to /dev/null

`nohup command &>/dev/null &`