# Script does not run in bg

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, background-process

I have the following simple forloop.sh script:

```
for i in 2 3 3 3 45
do
 sleep 10
 echo $i
done
```

I cannot seem to run it in background. I tried:

```
./forloop.sh &
```

but I don't seem to get control over the terminal. It just doesn't seem to run in bg. What am missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: For truly background execute, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164664/running-a-command-as-a-background-process-service

Answer (score 0):

That is not right observation. This command:

```
./forloop.sh &
```

will run the script in background. It is only due to the fact `echo` line will write a `$i` on stdout and it might appear that script is not running in background.

If you press enter then prompt will show up for 10 seconds (as long as `sleep 10` ends).